# ADB shell command to refresh android phone screen

Tags: android, adb, hdmi

I modified android phone hdmi output properties using ADB commands below

```
adb shell setprop persist.demo.rotationlock false
adb shell setprop persist.demo.singledisplay true
```

In order to see the change,
I will have to do either one of the following.

- turn off phone screen, then turn on phone screen.
- restart the phone or tv
- unplug the phone to monitor, then plug the phone to monitor.

What I want:
Is there any command to do a quick reload/reset/refresh phone screen or video output connection? so I don't have to do any of the above to see the change.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

- To "turn off phone screen, then turn on phone screen":

  `adb shell input keyevent 26`

  Run the above command *twice*.
  26 is the keyevent code for power button.
- To "restart phone":

  `adb reboot`